# MySQL database hosted online

Tags: mysql, database

So I have created a mysql database hosted at db4free.net, and am able to access it easily from the command line or from java.  My concern however, is I can only access it using my own username, password credentials.  I tried to create user, but it appears I cannot as I get `Access Denied`.  I'm assuming I don't have privileges to create users from this hosted database.

Now I want to include access to this online database in my application, but I don't know how without having major security issues.  The only apparent way for another user to connect would be to include my own username, password credentials for the database but that is very unsafe.

Any ideas on how I can provide database access to users safely ?

Comment: _•db4free.net is a service for testing, not for hosting._ http://www.db4free.net/conditions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the front door page of the service you're using:

> What db4free.net is not
>
> db4free.net is a testing service which means it is not suitable for
>   production. There can be outages, data loss and security features do
>   not meet the standards which you expect from a professional data
>   hosting provider. If you need a MySQL database for production use,
>   please do not use db4free.net!

This seems pretty clear to me. Don't do what you're hoping to do!

Plus, it's not a good idea security-wise to open up a MySQL server to the public internet without using secured connections. Even then it's questionable. Somebody who reverse-engineers your app can pwn your database.